# Can this site be built using wordpress?

Tags: development-strategy

I want to know if this site can be built with wordpress, I'm a programmer and I don't know anything about wordpress, how I'm just to get some good advices from you guys:

The main aim of the site is to allow users to view several places of interest in a country

Administrator:
-create a place of interest
- add,delete,edit details such as place name, address, location with google map,rating(users can vote a place),latitude, longitude
-add reviews for place on interest

Users:
-allow users to register
-contribute to site by adding a place of interest with all its details(will then be approved by the administator)
-add reviews to a place of interest
-up vote or downvote a place of interest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes. Theoretically any site can be built on top of Wordpress.

### Long Answer

You are going to need a lot of modifications to the standard Wordpress theme. But not to fret I have assembled a list of some of the things that you would need to do to get your feet wet.

1. Add *Custom Post Type* for Places ([Guide](http://www.doitwithwp.com/how-and-why-to-create-custom-post-types/) | [Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/))
2. Add *Custom Meta Boxes* for address, latitude, longitude, etc. ([Guide w/PHP Class](http://www.farinspace.com/wordpress-meta-box-next-level/))
3. Assign *Roles* to users that will allow them to post. I suggest the [Contributor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor) role. If you need more control over permissions you can use the [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin
4. Add a [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/installation/) plugin
5. Allow comments on posts to be used as reviews

*Note: I see that you have tagged wordpress.com. I am unsure of what limitations they place on themes and plugins.*

Comment: @imHacaoc, some people are suggesting to built this site using Drupal, what do you suggest??

Comment: I cannot speak for Drupal development. I have only tried it once and the theming was too obscure for me to follow. Saying this I say go for Wordpress, but that is a bias opinion. But I am sure both platforms are more than capable of running your website. It depends on which you feel more comfortable coding for and how it handles the administration section. Personally, I prefer Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Your fastest approach would be to use a plugin like Easy Google Maps: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-gmappity-easy-google-maps/

Based on the features you have listed you would need additional plugins, or--more likely--hire an expert developer to help build the site with these custom features as a new plugin.

Allowing users to register is fairly simple in WordPress. Plugins like Members allow you to customize what capabilities they have and there is a lot you can do on the back end with the WordPress admin API to make the experience more smooth.

This would be a huge undertaking, especially if you've never built a WP site before. If you are very proficient in PHP, you shouldn't have a problem catching up.

Best of luck on your venture.